# How to use RxJs to call backend with multiple and cancelable requests in paralell?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular application I have an observable that emits an Id based on user clicking a row in a grid.
Each time a new row is clicked I want to use the Id to call the backend to fetch data. But if the user clicks on another row before
the backend-call is finished, I want to cancel the first requests and fetch data for the newly selected row instead.

I want the requests to be run in parallell so using combineLatest is not the way to go, right?

I was thinking about something like this but the switchMap expects and return value....

```
changedSubject$.pipe(
switchMap(id => {
    callApiMethod1().subscribe(result1 => {
        subject1$.next(result1);
    });

    callApiMethod2().subscribe(result2 => {
        subject2$.next(result2);
    });
    
}).subscribe();
```

On my web-page I have two other components that is listening to the streams in subject1 and subject2 respectively. And do not need to be in sync, but show data for the selected row in the grid.

Any good patterns or practices to suggest?

Comment: You're saying *"if the user clicks on another row before the backend-call is finished, I want to cancel the first requests"* and then you say you want to run them in parallel. So which one you want?

Comment: Maybe the  the word parallel is wrong? The point is, I want to fire two requests as soon a row is clicked and handle the response, to update the subscribing view(s), as soon as the server responds. The response may not be in sync and the views may not update in sync either and that is just fine. The answer from Rafi is good I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by returning `merge`(or `forkJoin`) of both Observables without subscribing to them, and update the subjects using `tap` as in the following example:

```js
changedSubject$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(id => {
      return merge(
        callApiMethod1(id).pipe(tap(result1 => subject1$.next(result1))),
        callApiMethod2(id).pipe(tap(result2 => subject2$.next(result2)))
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```